Intellij "Workspace Resoluation" - Use linked gradle projects to resolve libraries
I have two gradle projects (call them A and B) in different git repos.
A uses B, i.e we have a dependency
//build.gradle.kts of Project A
...
dependencies {
   implementation("com.example.B:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
...

Both Projects are kotlin-based. So the rest of the build.gradle is the same for both projects:
// common parts of build.gradle.kts of A and B
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    //-> Only for B: implementation("com.example:B:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
// Publishing configuration
publishing {
    publications {
        // Create a Maven publication named "mavenJava"
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            // Publish the Java component of the project
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
    // Configure repositories for publishing
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() // Publish to local Maven repository
    }
}

I have also added both projects to the same IntelliJ Window, meaning that i use the little plus-sign in the gradle toolbar at the right ("Link Gradle Project").
I can start gradle tasks for both, that is fine so far.
But IntelliJ seems to miss that B is also loaded. When I start in a class from A and navigate into the sourcecode of B (using ctrl+click on the classname), I get a decompiled version of the classfile (that was loaded from mavenLocal()). I would expect it to jump into the sources that are loaded.
As far as I understand IntelliJ Documentation, that should work. It should detect the link and resolve the library dependency with the module sourcecode from the current workspace and not with the binaries/jar from mavenLocal. That feature was known in in maven as "workspace resolution" and I wonder why it is broken for my setup (minimal example).
Does that have to do with my setup (is it broken for kotlin or gradle?) or did I miss anyting?
Currently using IntelliJ Idea 2024.1

I don't think this functionality has been fully implemented for Gradle Projects yet, but you can try enabling external.system.substitute.library.dependencies Registry flag and check if it works for your Project(s).
To open the Registry press Shift twice and type registry in the search box.

yea, nice. That worked! I had to use File -> Invalidate Caches to make it work, but I can see usages of my classes in other projects now :)
